# C++ program crashes with no errors

Tags: c++

I am working on a fraction class in C++ and I am having a problem with this block of code:

```
ostream& operator << (ostream &out , Fraction &cfraction)
{
    int gcd = normalize (cfraction) ;
    cfraction.numerator /= gcd ;
    cfraction.denominator /= gcd ;

  try
    {
        if (cfraction.denominator < 0)
        {
            cfraction.numerator *= -1 ;
            cfraction.denominator *= -1 ;
        }
        //needs editing

        if (cfraction.denominator == 0)
            throw "Not defined" ;

        if (cfraction.numerator == 0 && cfraction.denominator != 0)
            out << cfraction.numerator ;

        if (cfraction.denominator == 1)
        {
            out << cfraction.numerator ;
        }

        else
            out << cfraction.numerator << "/" << cfraction.denominator ;
    }

    catch (const char* error)
    {
        cerr << "ERROR: " << error << "  " ;
    }

    return out ;
}
```

My program crashes if `cfraction.numerator` or `cfraction.denominator` equals 0 .

Can anybody help me by telling what exactly is the problem with my code ?

Update - Solved , had to check if gcd was zero . Thanks to everyone who answered .

Comment: Which line does it crash on?

Comment: Ask your math teacher or calculator: What is anything divided by zero.

Comment: Side note: outputting something is usually not expected to modify it, and the parameter should be a const reference (if it's a reference).

Comment: The greatest common divisor is not defined if any of the numbers is zero. You need to handle that as a special case. And a fraction is not defined if the denominator is zero, so you should have handled that case long before you reached this operator.

Answer (score 3):

If you divide by zero your program crashes. Thats the best it can do, because dividing by zero cannot yield a meaningful result. The only think you can do about it is to check for zeros before dividing, e.g.:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 0;
assert( b != 0 );
int c = a/b;
```

Typically you would want to replace the `assert` with some more reasonable error handling. In some rare cases it might even be meaningful to avoid division by zero by adding some epsilon before dividing. E.g.

```
double d = 1.0;
double e = 0.0;
double eps = 1.0e-10;
double f = d/(e + eps);
```

However, this can be dangerous as it hides some problem in the code (dividing by zero is almost always a problem).

Comment: Yes , I was dividing by zero . Problem was with my normalize function . Thanks for the help .